# Exception: com.hpe.application.automation.tools.common.SSEException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /rest/is-authenticated

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, alm

We are facing the issue while connecting to ALM through `jenkins` with HPE Application Life Cycle plugin.

Below is the implemenation:
`Selenium` with `TestNG->Jenkins->HPE Application Automation Tools->ALM`.

Error Message:

> Failed login to ALM Server URL: /. Exception: com.hpe.application.automation.tools.common.SSEException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /rest/is-authenticated

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are seeing does gives us a hint :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /rest/is-authenticated
```

A possible cause may be while passing the **`URL`** as an argument to **`get()`** method you might have missed to mention the **`protocol`** i.e. **`http`**

So a possible solution would be to pass the **`Fully Qualified URL`** as an argument to **`get()`** method as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: we have given the full URL with Protocol(http/https). But still getting the error.

Comment: We aren't writing any code. We are using the HPE Application Automation Tools jenkins plug in to update the results in ALM. But when run the build we are getting this error.

Comment: With HTTPS:
If we pass the ALM URL as https://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/  we are getting the following error:
Can't get authenticate header.
Failed login to ALM Server URL: https://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/. Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://alm.corp.chartercom.com/rest/is-authenticated 
If we pass the ALM URL as https://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/qcbin/.  we are getting the following error:
Login to ALM Server at https://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/qcbin/ failed. Status Code: 302
WARN: there's exception while uploading C:\Program Files

Comment: With HTTP:
If we pass the ALM URL as http://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/.  we are getting the following error:
Can't get authenticate header.
Failed login to ALM Server URL: http://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/. Exception: null
WARN: there's exception while uploading C:\Program Files 
If we pass the ALM URL as http://alm.corp.XXXXXcom.com/qcbin/.  we are getting the following error:
Can't get authenticate header.
Failed login to ALM Server URL: http://alm.corp.chartercom.com/qcbin/. Exception: null
WARN: there's exception while uploading C:\Program Files

Comment: Seems, it should go with ` HTTP` , look at the error `null WARN: there's exception while uploading C:\Program Files`. But I think this is not related to `Selenium`.

Comment: Thanks, But the problem here is that plugin is not getting logged in to the ALM server and it gives us the above error messages.